# Web Start application management?

Tags: macos, security, java

After the latest update Mac OS X Lion, I think that Apple disabled Java applications by default. When I try to run one, I get the following dialog:

[image]

If I choose to "Enable" it, how would I disable it later on? Is there any other way to enable this setting besides trying to launch a Java application (i.e. is there some place to manage this setting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *Java Preferences* app (located in the `Utilities` folder) to manage Java settings (also see [this reference](http://www.karthikk.net/2012/04/how-to-disable-java-on-mac-os-x-to-prevent-malware-injection/)).

**General steps**:

1. Go to your `Utilities` folder (either by going to the `Applications` folder or using the <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key combo from Finder)
2. Launch the `Java Preferences` application
3. Uncheck the box next to "Enable applet plug-in and Web Start applications"

**Screenshot**:

[image: Java Preferences screenshot]